# Could not find thread_safe-0.3.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I get this error while running bundle install in a rails app,

I thought the latest version is 0.2.0...could anybody help me out on this?

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find thread_safe-0.3.0 in any of the sources
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem.

The thread_safe gem version 0.3.0 has been yanked now from Ruby Gems: http://rubygems.org/gems/thread_safe/versions

So you might want to specify a different version in your Gemfile, or you can point the Gemfile directly to GitHub.

I solved the problem with this line in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'thread_safe', '0.2.0'
```

Comment: thanks this solved the issue! the actual command was 'bundle update thread_safe' as I had my thread safe locked at 0.3.0

Comment: Followed these steps and Gemfile.lock points to version `0.2.0` or earlier. Still get the same error when pushing to Heroku.

Answer (score 16):

As dreamnid said, "Look like they yank the 0.3.0 build a few hours ago to troubleshoot a [build issue](https://github.com/headius/thread_safe/issues/40)".

Try to run `gem uninstall thread_safe` (to remove yanked version) and later `bundle update` to install the correct versions.

Answer (score 8):

Running:

```
bundle update
```

Fixed the issue for me, with the message: "Using thread_safe 0.2.0 (was 0.3.0)"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I took mat_jack1's advice, but I also ran "bundle update thread_safe". That resolved the issue for me.