# Couldn't deploy to heroku with error: Could not find thread_safe-0.3.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I know about [this decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510461/could-not-find-thread-safe-0-3-0-in-any-of-the-sources) and I tried all advices, that were described

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
   New app detected loading default bundler cache
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
   Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Could not find thread_safe-0.3.0 in any of the sources
```

1) tried fully uninstall thread_safe
2) install different versions - 0.2.0 and 0.3.1

But I couldn't deploy app to heroku

Any ideas?

Comment: There does not appear to be a `0.3.0` version of this gem.  I know you tried 0.3.1, but maybe you forgot to commit your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock before you pushed to Heroku?

Comment: thanks....    i took next error, but not with thread_safe. I really don't know about commiting after editing Gemfile.