# Could not find thread_safe-0.3.5 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, capistrano, bundler, ubuntu-14.04

I get this error while running `cap production deploy` on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

It seems like a similar issue to here, but I've tried all the answers here but can't get it working [Could not find thread_safe-0.3.0 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510461/could-not-find-thread-safe-0-3-0-in-any-of-the-sources).

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@*serveripaddress*: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find thread_safe-0.3.5 in any of the sources
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find thread_safe-0.3.5 in any of the sources
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as root@*serveripaddress*: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find thread_safe-0.3.5 in any of the sources
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

---

Update: I've tried deploying to Heroku and get a similar error. If anyone has any advice it would be great.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 10017, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7613/7613), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10017/10017), 22.27 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 10017 (delta 2426), reused 7631 (delta 1548)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:        Detected buildpacks: Ruby, Node.js
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find thread_safe-0.3.5 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find thread_safe-0.3.5 in any of the sources
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to mysterious-badlands-3241.
remote:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find thread\_safe-0.3.0 in any of the sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510461/could-not-find-thread-safe-0-3-0-in-any-of-the-sources)