# pod install raise error to me how to solve

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I pulled iOS project from remote repository. Then I try to install new pod introduced from other developers by [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) tool, so I run `pod install`, but I get the following error:

```
pod install
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:313:in `to_specs': Could not find 'thread_safe' (~> 0.1) - did find: [thread_safe-0.3.6-java] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/john/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.5.0:/Users/john/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.5.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1472:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1461:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1461:in `activate_dependencies'
```

Why? How to solve?

**============== more info ======**

and when I check my ruby version by command `ruby -v` I get jruby version :

```
ruby -v
jruby 9.2.5.0 (2.5.0) 2018-12-06 6d5a228 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 12.0.2+10 on 12.0.2+10 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
```

why does it show jruby version instead of my ruby version I am using?

Comment: The problem may be due to JRuby which runs on the top of JVM. You can try without JRuby.

Comment: try `sudo gem update cocoapods`

Comment: Did you check this article? Maybe you should fix the thread_safe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510461/could-not-find-thread-safe-0-3-0-in-any-of-the-source

Answer (score 1):

This is related to updating your Mac to 10.15. This is caused by Cocoapods being in gem 2.3.0, while Catalina wants it to be in 2.6.0.

4 or 5 of solutions have been [posted on their github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8955). I personally haven't been able to get any of them to work, but based on emotes, this one worked for about 80 people:

> brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
>
> brew link --overwrite cocoapods
>
> [From @CathyXian on GitHub](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8955#issuecomment-539267256)